# Adding new values to an array nested within an object

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to create an array of objects, and inside each object I want a property called something like "valid paths" indicating where those objects can be found, but I'm having trouble adding new paths after creating the array.

For example:

```
    $Guids = $null
$Guids = @()
$Guids += [pscustomobject]@{
        Guid = '{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}'
        Paths = @()
        }
$Guids += [pscustomobject]@{
        Guid = '{7d83ee9b-2244-4e70-b1f5-5393042af1e4}'
        Paths = @()
        }
```

Here I am creating two objects indicating the guids I am looking for. Then to find and add the paths to the array, I do this:

```
    $Rootpath = "HKU:\$($CurrentUser.PSChildName)"
    $ShellFolderspath = "$RootPath\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"
    $UserShellFolderspath = "$Rootpath\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"
    
    #region 1 - Identify registry keys to update
    New-PSDrive -Name HKU -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_USERS -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    #Adding Downloads Guids to array
    ForEach ($object in $Guids)
    {
        #Check Shell Folders Path
        If ($Item = Get-ItemProperty $ShellFolderspath -Name $object.Guid -ErrorAction Stop)
        {
        "$($object.guid) found in Shell Folders path"
        $Object.paths += $Item.PSpath
        }
        
        #Check User Shell Folders Path
        If ($Item = Get-ItemProperty $UserShellFolderspath -Name $object.Guid -ErrorAction Stop)
        {
        "$($object.guid) found in User Shell Folders path"
        $Object.paths += $Item.PSpath
        }
    }
```

I've googled over and over and can't find any examples of anyone trying to do this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "I'm having trouble adding new paths after creating the array." - can you describe your "trouble"? What happens? Error messages? Array still empty? We can't see your screen :-)

Comment: The arrays were just failing to populate and appearing as "{}" in the table, but I guess I just needed to sleep on it. It seems to be working now.